# Android LockScreen event?

Tags: java, android

I have a question about the android system events. So I will get a event, if the user had put the wrong key into the lock screen on he's device. Also I will get a event if the user has put the correct key on he's device too...
Are there any events from this?

Greetings Fabian!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this somewhat using [the device administration APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html). Your `DeviceAdminReceiver` subclass -- itself a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver` -- will be informed of failed password attempts, and successful password attempts *after a previous failure*. What you will not find out about is successful password attempts in general. In theory, you could also listen for `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` and determine that the user must have entered their password correctly that way, though I have not tried to correlate these events and do not know if there may be issues.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin/PasswordEnforcer) from [an award-seeking book](http://commonsware.com/Android) that demonstrates receiving password events like this.